# OSGi list, what are those headers?

Tags: java, spring, osgi, apache-servicemix, spring-dm

I'm using Fuse ESB (ServiceMix) and I've been searching all over in the hope to find a better explanation of the various headers when running the command 'osgi:list'. Namely the two columns I want to understand are 'Blueprint' and 'Spring'. I have my guesses as to what their various statuses refer to, but then other scenarios come up which make me question this.

If anyone could provide some explanation, or better, point me to some documentation that explains the various columns and their potential values, that will be most helpful.

Comment: Can you post an example of the headers you're referring to?

Comment: Hi Chris, I am referring to the two column headers when running the command osgi:list, 'Blueprint' and 'Spring'. I have done much research but nothing has given a particular detailed answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here are the meanings of the various values that can show up in those columns:

Created - the blueprint/spring container was created and all dependencies were resolved successfully.

Creating  - the bundle is in the process of being created

Destroyed - the bundle's spring/blueprint container was completely destroyed (happens after it's unregistered as a service)

Failure - the bundle's spring/blueprint container failed to start (either due to an exception or a missing dependency after the grace period expires)

Grace Period - The bundle has 1 or more unsatisfied dependencies.

Waiting - the bundle is waiting on the availability of a service that satisfies a dependency

Full documentation can be found by reading the descriptions of the constants for [Blueprint](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/org/osgi/service/blueprint/container/BlueprintEvent.html). the Spring states mirror those definitions, though I can't find a good resource online for them. As for why they show up for only some bundles: they'll only have a value if the module contains either a blueprint or a spring file.

Comment: Thanks Chris, this helps with my question. Do you have any online references for this? Also, what does a bundle require to see such states in either of those columns? I ask this as I note some bundles display such values and others dont.

Comment: Also I note that sometimes these state values disappear, are they displayed for such a period of time?

Comment: I edited my response to include a link to the blueprint docs. I don't really know why the states go away after some time. Though you can get the current state of the bundle from the State column to know if it is Active, Resolved or Failed.

Comment: Section '6.2. Application Context Creation' appears to provide some context to the Spring DM side: http://static.springsource.org/osgi/docs/2.0.0.M1/reference/html/bnd-app-ctx.html

Answer (score 2):

Apache ServiceMix is using Gemini Blueprint and Spring.

According to [Apache website](http://servicemix.apache.org/docs/4.4.x/quickstart/index.html), those columns displays states of bean resolution defined in Blueprint XML and Spring XML files if they are present in the bundle.

For example *Created* value means that all bean dependencies have been resolved and injected.

Comment: Thank you Aries for this answer. I have read this article but I didn't feel it particularly elaborated on the meaning of these columns and their particular states/lifecycle.